# Variable resets to default value when I decorate object

Tags: java, enums, decorator

I'm trying to learn the Decorator Design Pattern. In this example, I create an app that calculates the cost of a coffee based on its type (espresso, decaf, house blend), size (tall, grande, venti), and condiment-decorators (soy, whipped cream, steamed milk) -- some code excluded for brevity.

As you can see from the output at the bottom, if I setSize(GRANDE) and don't wrap the object, getSize() returns GRANDE.

If I setSize(GRANDE), then decorate the object, getSize() returns TALL (the default value set in the Beverage class).

If I setSize(GRANDE), decorate the object, setSize(GRANDE) again, then getSize() returns GRANDE.

Note: Though the sizes don't print correctly, the costs are calculated correctly.

QUESTION: Is there a way to code this so when I setSize() it keeps that value even after the object is decorated?

```
package coffee;

public abstract class Beverage {
    String description = "Unknown Beverage";
    public enum Size { TALL, GRANDE, VENTI };
    Size size = Size.TALL;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setSize(Size size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Size getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public abstract double cost();
}
```

---

```
package coffee;

public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {
    public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

---

```
package coffee;

public class HouseBlend extends Beverage {

    public HouseBlend() {
        description = "House Blend Coffee";
    }

    public double cost(){
        return .89;
    }
}
```

---

```
package coffee;

public class Soy extends CondimentDecorator {
    Beverage beverage;

    public Soy(Beverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", Soy";
    }

    public double cost() {
        double cost = beverage.cost();
        if( beverage.getSize() == Size.TALL) {
            cost += .10;
        } else if( beverage.getSize() == Size.GRANDE) {
            cost += .15;
        }else if( beverage.getSize() == Size.VENTI) {
            cost += .20;
        } 
        return cost;
    }   
}
```

---

```
package coffee;
import coffee.Beverage.Size;
public class StarbuzzCoffeeController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beverage beverage = new HouseBlend();
        System.out.println( beverage.getSize() + " " + beverage.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage.cost() ));
        beverage.setSize(Size.GRANDE);
        System.out.println( beverage.getSize() + " " + beverage.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage.cost() ));
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        Beverage beverage2 = new HouseBlend();
        beverage2.setSize(Size.GRANDE);
        System.out.println( beverage2.getSize() + " " + beverage2.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage2.cost() ));
```

If I don't follow this with another setSize() it prints "TALL" as the size on the next line:

```
        beverage2 = new Soy(beverage2); 
        System.out.println( beverage2.getSize() + " " + beverage2.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage2.cost() ));
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        Beverage beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
        beverage3.setSize(Size.GRANDE);
        System.out.println( beverage3.getSize() + " " + beverage3.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage3.cost() ));
        beverage3 = new Soy(beverage3);
```

If I setSize() again after I've decorated the object, the size prints correctly as GRANDE:

```
        beverage3.setSize(Size.GRANDE);
        System.out.println( beverage3.getSize() + " " + beverage3.getDescription() + " $" + String.format("%.2f", beverage3.cost() ));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT::

TALL House Blend Coffee $0.89

GRANDE House Blend Coffee $0.89

-----------------------

GRANDE House Blend Coffee $0.89

TALL House Blend Coffee, Soy $1.04

-----------------------

GRANDE House Blend Coffee $0.89

GRANDE House Blend Coffee, Soy $1.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `Soy` does not override the `getSize()` method - therefore, the default implementation of the base class is used. And the base class returns its own `size` member, which is initialized to TALL.

In order to fix this problem, you will have to override the `getSize()` method accordingly in your class `Soy`:

```
@Override
public Size getSize() {
    return this.beverage.getSize();
}
```

This will correctly return the size of the decorated object.

Comment: Also, you might consider refactoring your classes. At the moment, decorators are inheriting unnecessary members of the base class. I would propose a change where you have a minimal base class with only abstract methods (which are enough to describe the public API of your (decorated) objects). Then create one abstract class implementing those methods, which has backing private or protected members. Specific implementations, like `HouseBlend`, can extend this class.

Comment: Create another abstract class (`BeverageDecorator`) implementing the base class' methods which has only one member - an instance of `Beverage`. All methods should delegate calls to this member. Decorators, like `Soy`, can extend this class and only override necessary methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the Decorator Pattern is not correct conceptually. The problem you're encountering comes from that incorrect implementation.

I'm referring below to the 5 items in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

1. "Subclass the original "Component" class into a "Decorator" class;"

   - in your case the "Component" is `Beverage` and `CondimentDecorator` is the Decorator
2. "In the Decorator class, add a Component pointer as a field;"

   - Add the Component pointer as a field. You added the field `Beverage beverage` in `Soy`, instead of adding it to `CondimentDecorator`
3. "Pass a Component to the Decorator constructor to initialize the Component pointer;"

   - This should be done in `CondimentDecorator` as well
4. "In the Decorator class, redirect all "Component" methods to the "Component" pointer"

   - You haven't done that, and it is the root of your issue. On a `CondimentDecorator`, by default, `getSize()` should call `beverage.getSize()`. The same should be done for all other fields.

I think you should go back to the basics of what the decorator pattern is trying to achieve, and rebuild your implementation with the right idea in mind. You might be able to fix your issue in a simpler way, but you might then have a wrong idea of what the decorator pattern actually is.

Keep in mind the principal idea that:

- Beverage is your Component,
- CondimentDecorator is your Decorator and,
- Soy is a ConcreteDecorator

Comment: Thank you, ARRG. I'll have to look at that. I got this Decorator structure and code from the book: Head First Design Patterns (http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124). It's possible the authors implement it in a roundabout way to dummy it down for beginners like myself.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to delegate `getSize()` to the wrapped/decorated instance if you want the value of the "original" beverage.

```
  Beverage cappuccino = new Cappuccino(Size.VENTI);
  Beverage soyMilkCappuccino = new Soy(cappuccino);
```

Inside `Soy`

```
  class Soy extends Beverage {
       private final Beverage decorated;
       Soy(Beverage other) { this.decorated = other; }
       // delegation
       Size getSize() { return decorated.getSize(); }
  }
```